# Securing php website(and website in general) in all Aspects

Tags: php, security

I dont know whether it is right to post it over here.

Can someones suggest some beginner resources for this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should say -1 for this question is worth it.. As I didnt have to waste my time searching for junks of php pages lurking around the web. Thanks a lot guys who posted the resources and are really useful.. Cheers to you patrolling guys....Good work keep it up!! :) 
And i should say this I will do it again and again whenever i feel I need help from stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found Added Bytes' [Writing Secure PHP](http://www.addedbytes.com/writing-secure-php/) a good guide when I was starting out with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is an exact duplicate of one of these questions, but you can start reading here in SO itself:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081243/which-are-the-common-security-issues-that-the-beginners-make-in-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119083/php-tutorial-that-is-security-accuracy-and-maintainability-conscious
- [Securing PHP forms for beginners? Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889643/securing-php-forms-for-beginners-resources)
- [Examples of vulnerable PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783137/examples-of-vulnerable-php-code)

Comment: @Amit I do not understand your comment. I did not vote to close this question.

Comment: I posted it in wrong place.. my bad.... Your answer is great help. I should delete the comment

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the resources already posted, here are some points to keep in mind:

- Never trust any data that comes from the client, you must assume it may be malicious
- Keep printed error messages generic, they help attackers reverse engineer your code
- Turn indexes off through your .htaccess file (plenty of tutorials on google)
- Encrypt all critical data such as passwords
- Understand the high-level differences between encryption options (AES,MD5,SHA,etc)

You should also be familiar with how some common attacks work such as SQL Injection and Cross Site Scripting (XSS)