# sending html form data to php

Tags: php, html, drupal

I am using a drupal site.here is the code I have written in client side

```
<form  method="get">
Email :<input type ="text" name ="email" size ="20"><br />
<button style="width:65;height:25" onClick='email_direction_data()'><b>Send</b></button>
</form>
```

when I click the button page will refresh.text field is used for enter the email address.I have written below code inside a drupal module file in a function to send an email.

```
  drupal_mail('direction', 'invitation', $_GET['email'] , language_default(), $params);
```

but the text field content is not going to GET array when I click the button.what is the reason for that?is there any wrong in my code?

Comment: If creating a custom module, you should use Drupal's form api instead of hard-coding the HTML

Comment: What does your `email_direction_data()` function do?

Comment: @laxman13: you cannot post from a remote none-fapi form to a fapi callback (mass assigment etc prevention). It seems the OP is trying to do that.

Comment: @berkes I know you can't go from a non-fapi form to a fapi callback, was suggesting he create the form using the fapi instead to make his life easier.  Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @laxman: you are correct. For clarity: _if_ you can write both the Form and the Form-handling in Drupal: use FAPI. If one of both is done in an external application: don't use FAPI.

Comment: @pifantastic: when I click the button that function is triggered.it is located at a js file.is it related to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have an html `<input type="submit" />` button, not a `<button>` tag.

Comment: :I did as you said.but still text field content is not going to server...:(..what happening?

Comment: You also didn't specify `<form action="http://mysite.com/mygeturl">`

But I just noticed you're writing this inside a Drupal module file. It might be a mess if you don't use drupal's form API. I don't use Drupal so it might not be as simple as writing raw HTML.
Like @Laxman13 said, you should probably use Drupal's Form API: http://drupal.org/node/751826

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that you have just written the perfect spam-relay, now, have you?

In order to give you a secure and solid solution, I would be writing both a book on basic webdevelopment and drupal development in this answer.

I suggest you take a little more time to get to learn basic webdevelopment, security basics and some initial understanding of Drupal-development.

- http://docforge.com/wiki/Web_application/Security
- [Securing PHP forms for beginners? Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889643/securing-php-forms-for-beginners-resources)
- http://www.drupalbook.com/